# How to decide variable names to be used angularjs

Tags: angularjs, naming-conventions

I am little bit confused about how to decide shorten names for variables when using `<li ng-repeat="cat in categories>`. So here i have used `cat`, why not any another word?

Sometime I notice that people use single characters like `<li ng-repeat="m in members>`

Is there any general *mechanism* to define it?

Comment: Those are variable names.  The "mechanism" used to define them is human intuition.  Use names which are clear, understandable, convenient, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with any language. Its more about having a **relevant** variable name so that we can easily understand it when we see it in the middle of `html` etc.So, rather than

```
<li ng-repeat="cat in categories>
```

this one makes more sense

```
<li ng-repeat="category in categories>
```

I hope that helps. The same logic is applied in all other languages  i.e meaningful names and that is self explanatory for its existence.

Comment: @SudhaKushwaha : https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/3092377 . You can find me on linkedIn

Comment: @SudhaKushwaha : Can you mark it as an answer if its what u were looking for